# Kill process from application, iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, unix, process

I need to kill process from my iPhone application.
I've got running process list with its PID. In unix you can kill process by typing in terminal "kill -9 PID" where -9 signal of the kill, but if I type it in my application like `system("kill -9 PID")` it doesn't work. :(
I've also tried `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL` but no result :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't kill a process but your own on a non jailbroken iOS environment.